# OpenCV error with pyramid mean-shift (cvPyrMeansShiftFiltering)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opencv

I am having trouble with cvPyrMeansShiftFiltering() function in OpenCV. Any call to it results in an "Assertion failed" message.

The following code fails on the line that calls cvPryMeanShiftFiltering:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cxcore.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string imageFile = "..\\bear.jpg";  
    IplImage* src = cvLoadImage(imageFile.c_str());
    int width = src->width;
    int height = src->height;
    IplImage* result = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height),8,3); 
    cvPyrMeanShiftFiltering(src,result,4.0,4.0,0);  

    cvReleaseImage(&src);
    cvReleaseImage(&result);
    return 0;
}
```

The program runs until the following error message is sent to the console:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (udata < (uchar*)ptr &&
>                  ((uchar*)ptr - udata) <= (ptrdiff_t)(sizeof(void*)+16)) in unknown function, file ......\src\cxcore\cxalloc.cpp, line 76

The assertion that fails is in cv::fastFree() in cxalloc.cpp. The program is running on Windows 7 (64bit), on VS 2008. The OpenCV version is 2.0.

I'll add that I've also tried this with OpenCV 2.1 on both VS2008 and VS2010. So it *must* be something that I'm doing, right? Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the last parameter != 0. That parameter (`max_level`) describes how many levels of scale pyramid will be used for segmentation and it doesn't make sense to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by applying the changes as described in https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/changeset/3081/trunk/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/segmentation.cpp

I recreated the dll file by creating the openCV.sln project as described in http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B_VS2010_CMake

The last parameter should indeed be different from 0 as well.